# postgresql.conf setting is ignored because it is defunct

Tags: postgresql, settings, greenplum, defunct, postgresql.conf

I'm trying to add 2 settings to my postgresql.conf file (on a CentOS Greenplum Postgres 9.4 instance) and I'm getting this message back:

```
log_destination"": setting is ignored because it is defunct
log_line_prefix"": setting is ignored because it is defunct
```

What does it mean?

This is the section where these settings are:

```
# If the execution time of the query is longer than the specified time, log the query text and execution time in the log
log_min_duration_statement = 0
# Information to prefix to the log message
log_line_prefix = '%t [%p]: [%l-1] user=%u,db=%d,app=%a,client=%h'  # '%t %d %u %p %h '
log_checkpoints = on
# Log the client's connection
log_connections = on
# Log client disconnects
log_disconnections = on
#Leave lock wait longer than the time specified by # deadlock_timeout (default 1 second) in the log
log_lock_waits = on
# Leave logs that temporary files were created (all 0's)
log_temp_files = 0
# Log language is limited to English
lc_messages = 'C'
log_destination = 'csvlog'
```

Comment: I do not find that error message in the source for Postgres 9.4, so what  is returning it? Where did you get the Postgres from? Are you using `include` files?

Comment: It's a Greenplum installation on Amazon. I'm not sure if I'm using include files..

Comment: You need to include that information in your question and/or tags. Greenplum is a different beast then the community Postgres. Someone who understands it, that is not me, will need to chime in

Answer (score 0):

Greenplum does its own logging and does not use those 2 settings. All of the logging goes to the master data directory for the master and segment data directories on the segments. That is expected behavior and currently can't be changed.

cd $MASTER_DATA_DIRECTY/pg_log/

and on segments

cd /data/primary/gpseg*/pg_log/